# iCarousel - Thread1 signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift3, icarousel

So I created an iCarousel and was able to successfully run it.  I did however need to load more than one carousel on the viewcontroller. I found the multiple iCarousels code and tried to adapt it to Swift.  Now unfortunately I get a Thread1 signal SIGABRT that shows on the line "class AppDelegate".  Really have no idea why it's doing this.

Please help me out!  Here's the code I have for the ViewController

```
class ChangeRoomViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, 
iCarouselDelegate {

    var hatsArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var shirtsArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var carousel1: iCarousel!
@IBOutlet weak var carousel2: iCarousel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    hatsArray = ["TopHat.jpeg", "WhiteBrimHat.jpeg", "StoutHat.jpg", "BaseballCapBlackw:Red.jpg", "WhiteBaseballCap.jpg"]
    carousel1.type = iCarouselType.cylinder
    carousel1.reloadData()

    shirtsArray = ["StarWarsBlackFittedT.jpg", "CollaredFittedWhiteWithBeigeSplash.jpg", "CollaredWhiteWithZigzagLightBlueStripes.jpg", "ClooaredBlackWithWhiteStripes.jpg", "CollaredFittedNavyBlue.jpg"]
    carousel2.type = iCarouselType.cylinder
    carousel2.reloadData()
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var hatsView : UIImageView!
    var shirtsView : UIImageView!

    if view == nil {
        hatsView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 65, width: 90, height: 60))
        hatsView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        shirtsView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 133, width: 90, height: 60))
        shirtsView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    } else {
        hatsView = view as! UIImageView
        shirtsView = view as! UIImageView
    }

    hatsView.image = UIImage(named: "\(hatsArray.object(at: index))")
    shirtsView.image = UIImage(named: "\(shirtsArray.object(at: index))")

    if (carousel == carousel1) {
        return hatsView
    }else {
        return shirtsView
    }

}

func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    if (carousel == carousel1) {
        return hatsArray.count
    }else {
        return shirtsArray.count
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recreate your error and it is caused by shirtsArray being empty and so the line

```
shirtsView.image = UIImage(named: "\(shirtsArray.object(at: index))")
```

causes the exception you encountered.

I am not sure why, but if you move the line

```
    shirtsArray = ["StarWarsBlackFittedT.jpg", "CollaredFittedWhiteWithBeigeSplash.jpg", "CollaredWhiteWithZigzagLightBlueStripes.jpg", "ClooaredBlackWithWhiteStripes.jpg", "CollaredFittedNavyBlue.jpg"]
```

to be just under the assignment to hatsArray, then it works.

Your viewForItemAt function is a bit messy. Why are you creating images/views for both carousels before deciding which one is required?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!  Strange though it manages to null the exception... Perhaps it's due to a conflict with "coursel1.reloadData()"

Comment: Regarding you last question...  I thought I needed to do it that way because both carousels will always be loading images at the same time.  There will never be an instance where only one carousel loads.  Could you elaborate or give an example on how you feel I should have tackled it?

Comment: The function will get called twice, once for each carousel with the carousel parameter set accordingly. If you test which one at the beginning of the function, you only need to set up the imageView for the particular carousel being called.